# MEAN Stack App - Splitting UI and backend code between 2 servers

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mean

For a MEAN stack based application, I'm wanting to run the UI code on one server and the backend code on another server.  Anyone aware of any Github projects that show MEAN project setup in this fashion?  For the server w/the UI code, it shouldn't have any Controllers, Services, DAOs, MongoDB configuration "db.js" or running MongoDB instance.  The backend code on the 2nd server would have all of the Controllers, Services, DAOs, Rest API, MongoDB config "db.js" and running MongoDB instance should be present.

I'm hoping to get some examples.  There are tons of MEAN examples out on the net and in Github, but I haven't found an example where the split the MEAN stack between different servers like I'm wanting.

Comment: There are plenty of examples of creating a REST API with Node + Express + Mongo. That's your back-end server.  Server config isn't something you often see on Github, but if you know how to build an Angular app that consumes an API (there are also many examples of that) then you have all the pieces you need. Just serve your static web client up with your HTTP server of choice (I suggest Nginx) and build your REST API in Express. If there's a specific part of that tripping you up, post some code here showing what you tried and describing the problem.

Comment: If you can use AWS, you can host your Angular website on S3 as a static website, so essentially Amazon would manage the UI server for you...you just copy your web resources to S3.  Then host you REST API where ever on a server of your choice (Node+Express/Hapi+Mongo).  You may also want to consider using a hosting service for MongoDB, such as Atlas or mLab.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the easiest and better way to do what you want actually:
You need two separate directories in your system:

1. **Frontend** - use for client(UI)
2. **Backend** - use for Server(which is for DB and routers and controllers)

**Follow below steps to setup the frontend project only:**

a. Install angular cli

```
npm install -g angular-cli
```

b. Make Project

```
ng new my_frontend_app
```

c. Go to project Directory and install NPM modules

```
cd my_frontend_app
npm install
```

d. Run the Project

```
ng serve
```

**Below are the steps to Make Backend (express and jade engine) Project:**
a. Install Express Generator

```
npm install -g express-generator
```

b. Create Project

```
express my_backend_app
```

d. Go to project Directory

```
cd my_backend_app
```

e. Run the Project

```
npm start
```

**Now you can set the environment varibales in client(my_frontend_app) pointing to the server(my_backend_app) and deploy separately.**